# Outdated tokens in use system message

Tags: wordpress

I have the system message below after updating to civicrm 5.70.0 on Wordpress 6.4.3. My question is for the 1st one: Do I just replace `$participant.id` (as I find it without the curly brackets) with {participant.id} or just participant.id?
For the 2nd one: in the if and foreach below do i replace $dataArray with {found within $taxBreakDown} (with the curly brackets) ?

{foreach from=$dataArray item=value key=priceset}

{if !empty($dataArray)}

---

You are using tokens that have been removed or deprecated.

Please review your event_online_receipt message template and remove references to the token {`$participant.id`} as it has been replaced by {participant.id}

Please review your event_online_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$dataArray} as it has been replaced by {found within $taxBreakDown}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alert is because you have a custom implementation of the System message template `event_online_receipt`.

If there are minimal custom changes to your template, such as a header addition or image logo, it would be advisable to revert the template to its default state and then reapply your modifications on top of the updated HTML.

If there are complex custom additions to your template, pretty sure for the first, a simple replacement with `{participant.id}` is required (including brackets).

Eg, if you have

```
{if $isPrimary || $participant.id === $currentParticipant.id}
```

replace it with

```
{if $isPrimary || {participant.id} === $currentParticipant.id}
```

Re `$dataArray`, its a bit complicated and not just a replacement with `{found within $taxBreakDown}`. I think best would be to compare your template with the default HTML and then choose, which part is required, can be omitted, etc.