# Outdated tokens in use - help please

Tags: civicontribute

### I need some help please.
After i upgraded CiviCRM to 5.70  these alerts pop up.
How do i fix this.
Any help please.
What should i change...please. Thanks

You are using tokens that have been removed or deprecated.

### Please review your membership_offline_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$dataArray} as it has been replaced by {found within $taxBreakDown}
Please review your membership_online_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$dataArray} as it has been replaced by {found within $taxBreakDown}

Comment: Have answered a similar question here - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/47585/245. Does that help?